# gganimate attempt fails with error in adding element to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm trying to animate a map, and failing to execute the transition_states function.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

library(gganimate)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

# We'll start with a static plot
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Petal.Length)) + 
    geom_point()

plot(p)

anim <- p + 
    transition_states(Species,
                      transition_length = 2,
                      state_length = 1)

Error: Don't know how to add transition_states(Species, transition_length = 2, state_length = 1) to a plot
```

This error is unfortunately vague, and has few applicable questions here (or elsewhere). I'm eager for any advice about where to look.

Comment: code works as expected for me. try resetting your session and running again?

Comment: Interesting. When I run the code in a clean work session it works. There must be another package loaded that interferes with gganimate. Thanks for the second opinion. I'll update as I learn more.

Answer (score 0):

gganimate would not function properly with ggtern installed. Once I removed ggtern, gganimate worked as expected.